# Airflow ExternalTaskSensor Stuck

Tags: python, airflow-scheduler, airflow

I am trying to get the Airflow ExternalTaskSensor to work but so far have not been able to get it to complete, it always seems to get stuck running and never finishes so the DAG can move onto the next task.

Here is the code I am using to test:

```
DEFAULT_ARGS = {
    'owner': 'NAME',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 9, 9),
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False
}

external_watch_dag = DAG(
    'DAG-External_watcher-Test',
    default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS,
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(hours=1),
    schedule_interval=None
)

start_op = DummyOperator(
    task_id='start_op',
    dag=external_watch_dag
)


trigger_external = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id='trigger_external',
    trigger_dag_id='DAG-Dummy',
    dag=external_watch_dag
)

external_watch_op = ExternalTaskSensor(
    task_id='external_watch_op',
    external_dag_id='DAG-Dummy',
    external_task_id='dummy_task',
    check_existence=True,
    execution_delta=timedelta(minutes=-1),
    # execution_date_fn=datetime(2019, 9, 25),
    execution_timeout=timedelta(minutes=30),
    dag=external_watch_dag
)

end_op = DummyOperator(
    task_id='end_op',
    dag=external_watch_dag
)

start_op >> trigger_external >> external_watch_op >> end_op
# start_op >> [external_watch_op, trigger_external]
# external_watch_op >> end_op


# Below is the setup for the dummy DAG that is called above by the Trigger and watched by the TaskSensor
dummy_dag = DAG(
    'DAG-Dummy',
    default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS,
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(hours=1),
    schedule_interval=None
)

dummy_task = BashOperator(
    task_id='dummy_task',
    bash_command='sleep 10',
    dag=dummy_dag
)
```

I have tried tweaking this code a number of ways but have not gotten any success with the ExternalTaskSensor.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem and get the ExternalTaskSensor to work properly?  I have also read that issues can arise through scheduling intervals when using the ExternalTaskSensor, is it possible that part of the issue is that the DAGs both have `schedule_interval=None`?

I had gotten this to work with both of the DAGs set to the exact same `schedule_interval`, but that will not work in production.  The goal is to have the main DAG, **external-watch-dag** to be on a regular schedule and trigger that **DAG-Dummy** during its run, with the **DAG-Dummy** itself having `schedule_interval=None`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By default the `ExternalTaskSensor` will monitor the `external_dag_id` with the same execution date that the sensor DAG. With `execution_delta` you can set a time delta between the sensor dag and the external dag so it can look for the correct `execution_date` to monitor. This works great when both dags are run in a schedule because you know exactly this timedelta.

**The problem**: when a dag is triggered manually or by another dag, you cannot known for sure the the exact execution date of any of these two dags.

**The solution**: because you are using the `TriggerDagRunOperator`, you can set the `execution_date` parameter. This will make sure that the execution date from your dag and the external dag is the same. From the [docs](http://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/operators/dagrun_operator/index.html#airflow.operators.dagrun_operator.TriggerDagRunOperator):

> execution_date (str or datetime.datetime) – Execution date for the dag (templated)

So your code will look like this:

```py
trigger_external = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id='trigger_external',
    trigger_dag_id='DAG-Dummy',
    dag=external_watch_dag,
    execution_date="{{ execution_date }}",  # Use the template to get the current execution date
)
external_watch_op = ExternalTaskSensor(
    task_id='external_watch_op',
    external_dag_id='DAG-Dummy',
    external_task_id='dummy_task',
    check_existence=True,
    execution_timeout=timedelta(minutes=30),
    dag=external_watch_dag
)
```